# storing value against variable name "QW1I5K20" in an array element Q[1,5,20] using R

Tags: arrays, r, string, excel, csv

I have an excel file (.csv) with a sorted column of variable names such as "QW1I1K5" and numerical values against them.
[image: column 1 variable name , column 2 : value]
this list goes on for 
W from 1 to 15
I from 1 to 4
K from 1 to 30
total elements = 15*4*30 = 1800

I want to store the numerical values against these variables in an array whose indices are derived from the variable name .
for example QW1I1K5 has a value 11 . this must be stored in an array element Q[1,1,5] = 11 ( index set of [1,1,5] corresponds to  W1 , I1 , K5)

Comment: your solution is great ! I am a new user and did not realize that multiple answers cannot be accepted on par.

Comment: I had one more question though . Q <- array(dat$Col2, dim=c(15,4,30)) .. In  my case col2 has values stored in the order of [1,1,1] then [1,1,2] then [1,1,3] etc..  instead of [1,1,1] then [2,1,1] then [3,1,1] .. could you suggest a solution to this one ?

Comment: @akrun. Thanks for the feedback ! I will improve as i get used to stackoverflow .

Comment: You can use `order`. I will update the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be this helps

```
Q <- array(dat$Col2, dim=c(15,4,30))

dat$Col2[dat$Col1=='QW1I1K5']
#[1] 34
Q[1,1,5]
#[1] 34

dat$Col2[dat$Col1=='QW4I3K8']
#[1] 38
Q[4,3,8]
#[1] 38
```

If you want the `index` along with the values

```
library(reshape2)
d1 <- melt(Q)
head(d1,3)
#  Var1 Var2 Var3 value
#1    1    1    1    12
#2    2    1    1     9
#3    3    1    1    29

Q[1,1,1]
#[1] 12
Q[3,1,1]
#[1] 29
```

#### Update

Suppose, your data is in the `order` as you described in the comments, which will be `dat1`

```
indx <- read.table(text=gsub('[^0-9]+', ' ', dat1$Col1), header=FALSE)
dat2 <- dat1[do.call(order, indx[,3:1]),]
Q1 <- array(dat2$Col2,dim=c(15,4,30))
Q1[1,1,2]
#[1] 20
dat2$Col2[dat2$Col1=='QW1I1K2']
#[1] 20
```

#### data

```
Col1 <- do.call(paste,c(expand.grid('QW', 1:15, 'I', 1:4, 'K',1:30),
            list(sep='')))
set.seed(24)
dat <- data.frame(Col1, Col2=sample(1:40, 1800,replace=TRUE))

dat1 <- dat[order(as.numeric(gsub('[^0-9]+', '', dat$Col1))),]
row.names(dat1) <- NULL
```

Comment: I like the array option you've presented here. +1

Comment: I love the expand grid command. I have bee using nested for loops to generate the variable names iteratively .

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest looking at using "data.table" and setting your key to the split columns. You can use `cSplit` from my "splitstackshape" function to easily split the column.

Sample Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  V1 = c("QW1I1K1", "QW1I1K2", "QW1I1K3", 
         "QW1I1K4", "QW2I1K5", "QW2I3K2"),
  V2 = c(15, 20, 5, 6, 7, 9))
df
#        V1 V2
# 1 QW1I1K1 15
# 2 QW1I1K2 20
# 3 QW1I1K3  5
# 4 QW1I1K4  6
# 5 QW2I1K5  7
# 6 QW2I3K2  9
```

Splitting the column:

```
library(splitstackshape)
out <- cSplit(df, "V1", "[A-Z]+", fixed = FALSE)
setnames(out, c("V2", "W", "I", "K"))
setcolorder(out, c("W", "I", "K", "V2"))
setkey(out, W, I, K)

out
#    W I K V2
# 1: 1 1 1 15
# 2: 1 1 2 20
# 3: 1 1 3  5
# 4: 1 1 4  6
# 5: 2 1 5  7
# 6: 2 3 2  9
```

Extracting rows:

```
out[J(1, 1, 4)]
#    W I K V2
# 1: 1 1 4  6

out[J(2, 3, 2)]
#    W I K V2
# 1: 2 3 2  9
```

Comment: Thanks ! didn't know about the"splitstackshape". The package looks really useful and is fast !

Comment: This is a more complete solution if the data is not sorted and has to completely follow the 'index' of the variable

Comment: Couple of more questions .  a). how to avoid the column of NA values after using cSplit ; b). I want the final result to be like finalarray[1,1,4] = 6. and not as a data frame .

Comment: @VM1, (a) Not sure what column of `NA`s you're referring to; (b) You can always do something like `out[J(2, 3, 2)][["V2"]]` to get just the value of interest from the "V2" column (or whatever it may be called in your actual dataset).

Comment: I tried using  out <- cSplit(df, "V1", "[A-Z]+", fixed = FALSE) after creating your data frame df , it generates a data table of 5 variables ( namely V2 , V1_1 , V1_2, V1_3, V1_4) the column of V1_1 has NA values for all rows .